# Replace match with next item from a list of replacement strings

Tags: python, file-io

Suppose I have a text. It has some duplicate values that should be changed. Basically I want to generate an input file for a program from the data I have. The duplicates need to be replaced by string variables from the list I have.

There is a great number of examples how to do this but they mostly loop through lines. However text can occur on a line once, several times, or never. It is also important that when the duplicate appears first it is replaced by the first element in the list an so on.

A small example.

Input text:

```
wefhwefhef AAA fghfhrjgrjr
AAA rhrfgjhrgjrehgj r
grnggrejg
grejren AAA
ff34t r4 43r 43r 43 AAA ff34 f43f3443fgh5 AAA
```

List of variables:

```
['FIRST', 'SECOND', 'THIRD', 'FOURTH', 'FIFTH']
```

Expected output:

```
wefhwefhef FIRST fghfhrjgrjr
SECOND rhrfgjhrgjrehgj r
grnggrejg
grejren THIRD
ff34t r4 43r 43r 43 FOURTH ff34 f43f3443fgh5 FIFTH
```

Here is what I have done so far. It does not work correct since it loops through lines, but I need to loop through occurrences. Additionally, I think I could also use the `enumerate` feature.

```
input = open('input.txt', 'r')
output = open('output.txt', 'w')

# otput.txt is the empty file
# input.txt is given in the example code

variables = ['FIRST', 'SECOND', 'THIRD', 'FOURTH', 'FIFTH']

index = 0
for line in input:
    output.write(line.replace('AAA', variables[index]))
    index += 1
input.close()
output.close()
```

Comment: A side note—it's not generally a good idea to use the name of built-ins like `input` as identifiers. You would be shadowing the built-in `input` function, preventing it from being used, and would almost certainly cause future confusion.

Comment: What should happen when you run past the end of the list? Start over from the first element?

Comment: @tripleee Nothing. I need to do the same for the other tag in the text (like 'AAA') using the other variable list. I need to do so to create a long xml-file with really complicated structure.

Comment: "Nothing" as in stop replacing, or "nothing" as in that cannot possibly happen, or "nothing" as in start yielding empty strings? If it's not important to you that's fine, but spelling out the corner cases can still be important to help guide solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str.replace()` doesn't allow you to pass in a function to say what the replacement should be, but `re.sub` does.  With that, you can do something like

```py
import sys
import re

def nextrep():
    while True:
        for replacement in ['FIRST', 'SECOND', 'THIRD', 'FOURTH', 'FIFTH']:
            yield replacement

replacement = nextrep()
rx = re.compile("AAA")

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = rx.sub(lambda x: next(replacement), line)
    print(line, end='')
```

This just uses `sys.stdin` as the read filehandle, and (implicitly) `sys.stdout` for writing. You can easily wrap it with different filehandles if you want to.  The following would replace the final `for` loop from the above script;

```py
with open(inputfile) as ifh, open(outputfile, 'w') as ofh:
    for line in ifh:
        ofh.write(rx.sub(lambda x: next(replacement), line)
```

The `while True:` makes sure we start over from the beginning of the list of replacements if we find more strings to replace than we have items in the list of replacements.  If you want a different behavior, it should be easy enough to modify `nextrep` to do something else when you run past the end of the list (raise an exception? Start yielding empty strings? Or yield the input string so you replace matches with themselves?)

If you have multiple strings you need to replace, this easily extends to that use case too; just expand the regex, and pass in the string to replace as a parameter to the replacement function so it can know which list to `yield` from.  That way, you only need a single pass over the text.  Perhaps something like this:

```py
import sys
import re

def nextrep(items):
    while True:
        for replacement in items:
            yield replacement

replacement = {
    'AAA': nextrep(['FIRST', 'SECOND', 'THIRD', 'FOURTH', 'FIFTH']),
    'BBB': nextrep(['PREMIER', 'DEUXIEME', 'TROISIEME'])
    }

rx = re.compile("|".join(replacement.keys()))

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = rx.sub(lambda x: next(replacement[x.group(0)]), line)
    print(line, end='')
```

This will replace the first `AAA` with `FIRST`, the first `BBB` with `PREMIER`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

To do this you need to tell `str.replace` that you only want to replace a single instance at a time.  Then loop through the possible terms.  It might look something like this:

```
original = open('input.txt', 'r')
output = open('output.txt', 'w')

# output.txt is the empty file
# original.txt is given in the example code

terms = ['FIRST', 'SECOND', 'THIRD', 'FOURTH', 'FIFTH']

text = original.read()

for term in terms:
    text = text.replace('AAA', term, 1)

output.write(text)

original.close()
output.close()
```

Output:

```
wefhwefhef FIRST fghfhrjgrjr
SECOND rhrfgjhrgjrehgj r
grnggrejg
grejren THIRD
ff34t r4 43r 43r 43 FOURTH ff34 f43f3443fgh5 FIFTH
```